# Is . char allowed in JSON field name?

Tags: json

Is . char allowed in JSON field name?

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: instance.id is not a valid JSON field name.
at com.google.gson.JsonFieldNameValidator.validate(JsonFieldNameValidator.java:52)
```

Atleast gson library seems to be complaining. But I couldn't find anything in json spec.

Note that I have serialized name annotation to avoid issue in java field name.

```
@SerializedName("instance.id")
private String instanceId;
```

Update:

It is a bug in serializedname and This is the fix I did:

```
   @SdeSerializedName("instance.id")
   private String instanceId;
```

and

```
     new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy
        (new FieldNamingStrategy() {
            public String translateName(final Field field) {
                final SdeSerializedName annotation = field.getAnnotation(SdeSerializedName.class);
                return ((null != annotation) && null != annotation.value()) ? annotation.value() : field.getName();
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowed in JSON itself, but (if I understand the GSON documentation correctly) the error message is because it can't map `instance.id` to a Java class member of the same name.

Have a look at Following thread about a similar problem mapping field names:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-05/e575bb65cdd30410?rnum=31&_done=/group/google-gson/browse_frm/month/2010-05?&pli=1

Comment: But I do have a serialzedname annotation - I have updated my question to clarify. So it might be a bug in serialzedname annotation handling.

Comment: It is a bug in serializedName annotation. Json spec. itself allows this. I added my own annotation @SdeSerializedName("instance.id") and added a new strategy. Added to the question for reuse.

Answer (score -1):

Since the dot "." is already the separator between an object and a member name in javascript (this is where json originates), it cannot be a valid field name.

Comment: Reasoning makes sense. But json spec. doesn't say so. http://www.json.org/ Also some other parsers actually parse it. Including Gson's JSonParser!!